# Syntax Error in UPDATE statement VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ms-access-2013

I get the Syntax Error in `UPDATE` statement whenever I try to update information in my Access database. I have tried moving things around and adding commas or taking away commas. I am stuck, any suggestions as to what I could do? The error is attached to the second `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` at the bottom.

```
if (txtdateId.Text != "")
{
    if (txtdateId.IsEnabled == true)
    {
         cmd.CommandText =
                "insert into tbEmp(DateofService, AssociateName, DeviceType, DeviceModel, Serial, Issue, Part1, Part2, Part3, RepairedBy, Campus) Values('" +
                txtdateId.Text + "','" + txtEmpName.Text + "','" + txtContact.Text + "','" + txttype.Text +
                "','" + txtserial.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtpart1.Text + "','" + txtpart2.Text +
                "','" + txtpart3.Text + "','" + txtrepaired.Text + "','" + txtcampus.Text + "')";
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         BindGrid();
         MessageBox.Show("Device Added Successfully");
         ClearAll();
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "update tbEmp set DateofService = ,'" + txtdateId.Text + ",AssociateName = '" + txtEmpName.Text + ",DeviceType = '" + txtContact.Text + ",DeviceModel = '" + txttype.Text + ",Serial = '" + txtserial.Text + ",Issue = '" + txtAddress.Text + ",Part1 = '" + txtpart1.Text + ",Part2 = '" + txtpart2.Text + ",Part3 = '" + txtpart3.Text + ",RepairedBy = '" + txtrepaired.Text + "where Campus = '" + txtcampus.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        BindGrid();
        MessageBox.Show("Device updated");
        ClearAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed several `'` in you statement also you have one extra `'` after `DateofService`. Your statement should be like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update tbEmp set DateofService = '" + txtdateId.Text + "',AssociateName = '" + txtEmpName.Text + "' , ...
```

Also I strongly recommend you to use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [`SQL Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) like this:

In SQL:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update tbEmp set DateofService = @txtdateId ,...";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("txtdateId",txtdateId.Text);
```

And for Access and OleDB:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update tbEmp set DateofService = ? , ....";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateofService ",txtdateId.Text);
```

Although specify the type directly and use the Value property is more better than `AddWithValue`. Check this: [`Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Actually, MS Access and OleDB don't support **named** parameters like `@txtdateId` - Access uses `?` and *positional* parameters only

Answer (score 0):

This is solution of your problem, but I'll prefer you do some add validation for SQL injection. First take the textbox value validate it then pass it query.

```
cmd.CommandText = "update tbEmp set DateofService = '" + txtdateId.Text + "' ,AssociateName = '" + txtEmpName.Text + "' ,DeviceType = '" + txtContact.Text + "',DeviceModel = '" + txttype.Text + "',Serial = '" + txtserial.Text + "',Issue = '" + txtAddress.Text + "',Part1 = '" + txtpart1.Text + "',Part2 = '" + txtpart2.Text + "' ,Part3 = '" + txtpart3.Text + "' ,RepairedBy = '" + txtrepaired.Text + "' where Campus = '" + txtcampus.Text + "'";
```

Comment: This is still missing some closing single quotes.